# React native how can we use drawer navigation inside stack header

Tags: react-native

I'm using the React navigation vs, and I want to use the drawer navigation inside the stack navigation because i have added the stack navigation on my project 
but I want to start drawer navigation from the Dashboard not on login screen

```
App.js

import Start from './App/Navigation/StackNavigation'
export default  class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(){

    super();

    global.DomainName = 'http://testing.njtennis.net/';
  }
  render() {

    return (  
    <Start/>

    )
```

Take a look on stack navigator screen

```
import { createDrawerNavigator,DrawerContentScrollView,DrawerItemList,DrawerItem,
  } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
// import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import LoginView from  '../../App/component/Views/Login'
import Test from  '../../App/component/Test'


  import SignUpView from '../../App/component/Views/Signup';
import Dashboard from '../../App/component/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

 <NavigationContainer style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}>
      <Stack.Navigator>

        <Stack.Screen name=" " component={FirstPage}   
         options={{
          headerShown:false,

        }}
         />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginView}
          options={{

            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#88aa31',
            },
           headerTintColor: '#fff',

          }} />

         <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignUpView}
          options={{

            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#88aa31',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
          }} />
         <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}

          options={{

         // headerTitle:()=> <Header   title={"Dashboard"}/>,
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#88aa31',
            },
            headerLeft: null,
              }} />
</NavigationContainer>
```

Can I add header and drawer navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I have created rough auth flow for react native. Inside `App.js` i have created `NavigationContainer` and inside it i have `DrawerScreen (Screen after login)` and `AuthScreen (Screen before login)`. Authentication state is maintained by `isLogin`.

Add respected Screen in DrawerNavigation and LoginStack accordingly to your need.

This code is pseudo code.

#### App.js

```
return (
   <NavigationContainer>
       { isLogin ? <DrawerNavigation /> : <AuthStackScreen /> }
   </NavigationContainer>
)
```

#### Drawer.js

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function DrawerNavigation() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

#### LoginStack.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function AuthStackScreen() {
  return (
       <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name=" " component={FirstPage}   
         options={{
          headerShown:false,

        }}
         />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginView}
          options={{

            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#88aa31',
            },
           headerTintColor: '#fff',

          }} />
       <Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```